# The relationship of/between company x and company y

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

> The relationship *of* company x and company y
>
> The relationship *between* company x and company y

Which one is the best for the context of law terms?

Comment: What do you mean by 'law terms'? Do you mean criminal law, civil law, business law, medical law,... Can you give an example of the types of companies are you talking about? Is this a question about two actual companies, or two hypthetical companies?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you want to designate the relationship between them in order to, for example, describe it (as good, bad, cooperative, competitive, etc.).

*The relationship between company x and company y* is correct. We normally do not use the other way.

*Between* is cited here in the example sentence provided for the relevant sense of *relationship:*

[3. an emotional or other connection between people:
*the relationship between teachers and students.*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/relationship)

Some English learners may feel that *the relationship of x and y* is correct because we sometimes use *[something] of [something]* similarly to **'s**. For example *the entrance of the building,* *a friend of my grandmother.* But we do not generally use this form for a possession of the type *X and Y's relationship*.

Comment: More detail would be helpful here. Why is it correct? What's wrong with the alternative?

Comment: @DavidRicherby Hi. More helpful to who? Do you have a question about this out of your own curiosity, or are you helping out by giving general advice for good answers? That will help me decide how to respond.

Comment: Your answer is correct (you could also mention that "relationship *of* X *to* Y" would be correct) and I'm giving advice for good answers. Explanation would make it more useful to everybody who doesn't already know the answer by helping them to answer any similar questions they might come up with in the future. You've given the man a fish but it would be better to [teach him how to fish](http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/m/maimonides326751.html).

Comment: I'm pretty new to giving answers, so I ask this in earnest: Why wouldn't you give a more complete or better answer yourself (or extend mine by editing)? There could be many reasons a person would be inclined to consider the incorrect alternative supplied, and an explanation of why an approach is (probably) incorrect needs that information. The *relationship of x to y* could be correct, as could with, and for that matter of! I'm forced to wonder if you are taking a condescending attitude toward me for answering what seems to be a simple question simply.

Comment: BTW, How do you know the OP is a man?

Comment: I haven't posted an answer myself because I haven't yet thought of a good explanation of why one phrase is natural and the other isn't; if I had such an explanation, I don't think it would be appropriate to extensively edit your answer by putting those words into your mouth. I'm sorry you feel I'm being condescending; that was not intended and I was simply trying to help you produce better answers and responding to the direct questions you asked me. And I'm not assuming the asker is a man; I'm making a direct reference to a proverb that uses the words "a man".